# Which is the efficient way of using spritekit in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, performance, swift

I am trying to draw a black rectangle in Xcode sprite and also having a physical body for it.
So which is the efficient way to draw a rectangle to get maximum performance ? 
Sprite with texture with a png(black)
 or 
Sprite node with CGRect (fill UIColor black)
or
SKshapenode (fill color black)
Could you please answer why it is efficient too ?
thanks

Comment: Why don't add the code you're using now?

Comment: The answer will depend on many things, the only way to know for your specific situation is to benchmark/profile in Instruments - this can also tell you why things are efficient/inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.
I will check with that.